# How to recover from failure when using SqlBulkCopy in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` to insert large amounts of data into SQL Server. The code is simple, like following:

```
using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    copy.BatchSize = 10000;
    copy.DestinationTableName = "MyTableName";
    // other parameters...

    copy.WriteToServer(reader);
}
```

The problem I'm having is the data volume is large, so it takes very long time to finish the copy operation. Sometimes there is transient errors in the network or in SQL Server, which would fail the `WriteToServer` call.

In these situations, I want to be able to continue the copy from the failed batch, instead of deleting all the data and doing the copy all over again from the very beginning. But I can't do this because at the time when I caught the exception thrown from `WriteToServer`, the `reader` object would have already been in a wrong position.

One solution I can think of is to cache the entire batch in my code. However that would mean I need to manage the memory for the cache. Also I believe this approach hurts performance a lot.

Is there any better ways? Thanks.

Comment: note: you might want to ensure `EnableStreaming` is set to `true`; as for the actual issue  - yeah, it is a tricky one: you can't tell which  rows were even sent onto the TDS stream, *let alone* which  ones made it to the server or were processed. One option might be to to the bulk insert into a staging table and only move it to the real table (`insert foo ([cols]) select [cols] from foo_staging`) once the bulk copy is complete; you could also use small batches and transactions, but that is overhead....

Comment: @MarcGravell why is the default for EnableStreaming false? I'm quite sure in .NET 4.0 using an IDataReader always did streaming (at least in row by row way). Now the default is to buffer data?